# replace ius php56u with php71u

Tags: yum, php

using ius repo and have php56u installed. want to upgrade to php71u. yum replace doesn't work to do this (yum replace php56u --replace-with php71u, also tried with yum replace php). is there an easy way to swap out one php with another in ius repo?

Answer (score 0):

```
yum remove php*
yum install php71u* (with list of modules)
```